# Logic-Apps+TextAnalitycs Bad Result

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using LogicApps + Cognity Services to analyze: "Señor Samuel, Por este medio expreso mi reclamo formal por el mal servicio que usted da al tardarse demasiado en realizar las actividades  asignados. Sin mas". but it gives me a neutral result (0.50), when the result should be negative. Is there any way to refine the result?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way for you to tune the result yourself. That said, I will pass this along to the team, so we can better understand what made the machine think that the sentiment was negative -- and fix the issue on our side.

Luis Cabrera | Text Analytics Program Manager | Microsoft